# When can I add In app purchases ? Google Android Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

Do I have to integrate In app purchase before publishing my app or can I do it after?

I want to publish a app on Google play store and make it free to download. And, if it gets some traction, I want to integrate In App Purchases.
I know that if I make it free for download it can't be reversed, but what about In App Purchases, can they be added later ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While, as you already noticed, you cannot turn free app into paid once released, yet you still can add paid features to already released of any type (free or paid) using in-app purchases mechanism. You can do these features at any time.